# Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}^2 }$ where $X_i$'s are i.i.d uniform on $(0,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-distribution

Let $X_{i}$ be i.i.d. Uniform(0,1) random variables. Compute

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}^2 }$$

Do we use the expected value of both to solve this?

Edit :I am thinking of using Wald's equation 
$E[X_{1} + X_{2} + ..... X_{n} ]= E[N]*E[X_{1}]$

And what to do about the square term in the denominator.

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I am really sorry - I think due to some error my work which I usually show below the question was not posted here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just divide the numerator and the denominator by $n$ and use SLLN to conclude that the almost sure limit is $\frac {EX_1} {EX_1^{2}}=\frac 3 2$. [Note that $(X_i^{2})$ is also an i.i.d. sequence].